# Time function in JS

Tags: javascript, css, time

I am trying to create a JS function hide the HTML element on before 11:00 AM on Monday - Friday and after 03:00:00 PM Monday - Friday and hide the element all day on Saturday && Sunday. Here is what I have so far. I think I am getting there but Time is very tricky. What am I missing here? Thanks!!

```
jQuery(function() {
/* your code here */
// days of the week
 var d = new Date();
 var weekday = new Array(7);
 weekday[0] = "Sunday";
 weekday[1] = "Monday";
 weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
 weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
 weekday[4] = "Thursday";
 weekday[5] = "Friday";
 weekday[6] = "Saturday";

 var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

// Gather Time
var startTime = "11:00:00 AM";
var endTime = "03:00:00 PM"
var hour   = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var second = d.getSeconds();
var ap = "AM";
if (hour   > 11) { ap = "PM";             }
if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12;      }
if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12;             }
if (hour   < 10) { hour   = "0" + hour;   }
if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
if (second < 10) { second = "0" + second; }
var currentTime = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + " " + ap;  
 
if(n == "Monday" || n == "Tuesday" || n == "Wednesday" || n == "Thursday" || n == "Friday")  {
 if(startTime > currentTime && currentTime < endTime){
jQuery( "div.rpress_fooditem[data-term-id='2']" ).css({"display":"none"});
}}
else
 jQuery( "div.rpress_fooditem[data-term-id='2']" ).css({"display":"block"});
 alert("other day");


 return currentTime;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings in your deciding if, not actual dates...

```
var startTime = "11:00:00 AM";
var endTime = "03:00:00 PM"
var currentTime = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + " " + ap;
if(startTime > currentTime && currentTime < endTime)
```

**UPDATE**

I would use `Date` then I would change the hours and minutes accordingly for `startDate` and for `endDate` and for `currentTime` I wound not change anything. I hope that make sense.

**UPDATE 2**

The real question is on what kind of Date are we operate on? Are we doing it in UTC or it depends to the Timezone of the user (taken from browser). If the answers is "based on timezone" than I will advise you to use library like momentjs or something like this because due to change of "Summer Time" that can change overtime you need library that updates that information. I wont elaborate about it more, you can reasearch what the problem is really about in google.

Comment: Sonic-- Random lacks sufficient reputation to make a comment, so tried instead to add this comment into the body of your answer: "Not very good with Time. How do i compare actual dates?"

Comment: Oh, shame on me

Comment: I don't understand. You saying I should just change Date() to Date.now instead? Example would be nice.

Comment: @Random Oh sorry, yes. `Date` not `Date.now()`. You need to use object.

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to figure out instead using 12 hours format i use 24 hours format instead and convert into string and it works fine! Thank you for your help